# QWebView not laying out properly

Tags: python, layout, pyqt

Even if I set the geometry for the QWebView it occupies the whole left over screen.

[image]
Even worse if I maxmize the window, there is a gap between the two widgets

[image]
Below is my code I wrote:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class twsearchbox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        hbx = QHBoxLayout()        
        self.setLayout(hbx)
        self.resize(1024,800)
        self.setWindowTitle('layout test')

        tbx = QTextEdit()
        tbx.setGeometry(0,0, 300, 550)
        tbx.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        hbx.addWidget(tbx, 0 , Qt.AlignLeft)

        wv = QWebView()
        wv.load(QUrl('twsearch_template.html'))
        wv.setGeometry(0,0,300,550)
        wv.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        hbx.addWidget(wv, 0 , Qt.AlignLeft)
```

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this in code (in c++) and found it a bit puzzling until finally I took a look at the source code for `QWebView`. It seems that `QWebView::sizeHint()` is hard coded to 800 x 600 (Qt 4.6).

This seems a bit odd to me but I'm not sure enough to report a bug for it. If somebody can post a comment to confirm or deny the correctness of it, that would be good :)

In any case, you should be able to override this behavior by setting min/max height/width as needed.

Also, to explain the other behavior you see, even if the `QWebView` was the width you specified (300), you would see a gap as the layout tries to break the horizontal space into equal sizes. With the `QWebView` defaulting to 800 wide, the layout is stealing space from the left box to satisfy the size needed for the right box. If you had a wide enough screen, you would eventually see both halves equalize in size as you stretched the window horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the problem by using http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qboxlayout.html#setStretch

and setting QWebView sizepolicy to expanding

webView->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);